# Why can't I login with the user name and password I signed up with?

Tags: discussion, login

I signed up using a user name and password, but when I click the "Log In" link at the top of the page, the only options avalilable are to login with google, facebook, yahoo, etc.  I don't want to give out my social media credentials!

Why can't I login with my user name and password?

Comment: Are you sure? It shows login using Google, Facebook, and Stack Exchange as the three options above "More login options."

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want to give out my social media credentials!

By the way, that's not what happens here. StackExchange uses [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), which means you get redirected to the actual login page for the provider you select. You log into them directly (SE can never see the username/password), and then the provider passes a token back to identify you. SE uses the email address as the token if you choose Google.

But in your case, if you actually signed up with a username and password on SE, then you should select the "Log in using Stack Exchange" button as grawity said.

Answer (score 3):

The accounts you sign up for, on SuperUser, Stack Overflow, or most such sites, are under the "Stack Exchange" button.